# Почему использование break для выхода из цикла (кроме бесконечных циклов) считается антипаттерном?

Tags: javascript

Допустим есть массив

`const arr = [44, 22, 454, 213, 76, 83, 23, 44, 99];`

Нужно проверить есть ли в массиве 2 и больше значений меньше 50.
Я делаю это так:

```
let count = 0;

for (let i in arr ) {

  if (arr[i] < 50) {
    counter++;

    if (counter == 2) {
   // do something
     break;
   }
  }
 }
```

Как можно по другому правильно реализовать этот код? 
что-то нагуглить ничего не удалось

Comment: `i in arr` и `arr[i]` взаимно несовместимы.

Comment: `let count = arr.filter(x => x < 50).length` (хотя возможно это менее оптимальный вариант)

Comment: На митапе слышал

Comment: Эникейщик, понял спасибо

Comment: andreymal, походу это оно

Comment: Наоборот, удобно. Вдруг у вас в массиве миллион чисел - зачем бегать по всему массиву, когда можно через break выходить сразу как только нашли то, что искали)

Comment: В основном потому что, если тело цикла большое, то тяжело искать все условия, при которых цикл завершается. Гораздо удобнее, когда условия продолжения цикла описаны при инициализации цикла - так легче понимать код. Конкретно в вашем примере ничего плохого в использовании break нету.

Answer (score 6):

Использование break для выхода из цикла в общем случае **НЕ** является антипаттерном.

Избегать нужно следующих вариантов:

1. Безусловный break:

   ```
   for (...) {
       // ...

       break;
   }
   ```
2. Условный break, который можно вынести в условия цикла:

   ```
   while(foo < 5) {
       if (bar > 0) break; // головоломка

       // ...
   }

   while(foo < 5 && bar <= 0) { // вот так понятно
       // ...
   }
   ```

   Однако, из этого правила есть исключение - в том случае, когда условие цикла является идиомой, break использовать можно:

   ```
   for(var i=0; i<10; i++) { // идиоматичный цикл от 0 до 9
       if (bar > 0) break; // сойдёт

       // ...
   }

   for(var i=0; i<10 && bar <= 0; i++) { // тоже сойдёт
       // ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте значение `counter` как условие выхода из цикла

```
let counter = 0;
let i=0;
for (i=0; i<arr.length && counter!=2 ;i++) {

  if (arr[i] < 50) {
    counter++;

    if (counter == 2) {
   // do something
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

```js
const arr = [44, 22, 454, 213, 76, 83, 23, 44, 99];

function arrLength(arr){
   let d = [];
   let key;
  for( key of arr ){
    if( key < 50 ){
      d.push(key);
    }
 }
 console.log( `количество чисел меньше 50: ${d.length}`   )
}

arrLength(arr)
```

```js
const arr = [44, 22, 454, 213, 76, 83, 23, 44, 99];
let arr2 = [];
for( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
  if( arr[i] > 50 ) continue
    arr2.push( arr[i]  );
    console.log(  `количество чисел ${arr2.length} : числа меньше 50: ${arr[i] }`   )
}
```